# Visual Studio 2017 Create Pull Request button disappear randomly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, pull-request, team-explorer

I have been using Visual Studio 2017 for developing an Angular 7 application with .NET Core.

Amazingly, the “Create pull request” button on the “Team Explorer” pane is not showing up in a random way.  Which leads me to open up the DevOps portal on the browser and issue the pull request after several clicks. 
This would be much easier if I could always use the VS built-in “Create pull request” button.

[image]

Developers have intrigued to discuss this matter and hold conflicting ideas.
From my experience, this issue was with VS 2017 from the beginning.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any workaround?

My Visual Studio version is shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If a Git repo is cloned by pasting in the URL in the Connect page, the Git operations (ex: pull, push) will work since they use the Git protocol.  But there is an additional connection to the Azure DevOps server that is needed for features like work items, builds, and pull requests to be enabled.

When you find yourself in this state, navigate to the Connect page in Team Explorer and see if you are connected to the remote project and repo.  If you are not, then click the Manage Connections link and launch the Connect dialog.  In the dialog, find your project and remote repo (from which you cloned the local repo) and connect to them.  As long as the origin remote URL in the Git repo matches the project/remote repo URL, then the connected features should start to work.

We are aware that it is too easy to end up using a Git repo without being connected to the server for the additional features.  We hope to improve this part of the experience in a future release.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to Azure DevOps at all, it is mainly the problem of your Visual Studio 2017 settings.

Looking at the screenshot of your VS 2017 about box, I see that you have installed many extensions. This may cause configuration problems. Also there's a possible MEF cache corruption. You should not install any extension that isn't proven to be compatible with your VS 2017 version, as the extension may not be able to keep up with VS 2017 updates and patches.

Try to reset Visual Studio by running `DEVENV.EXE /ResetSkipPkgs` in command prompt using "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017", then restart.

If this doesn't work, then you have to repair your VS 2017 installation by using Visual Studio Installer.